# XPATH Grab following sibling and stop at the next sibling in the tree

Tags: xpath

```
<div class="season-rate season-summer">
<p class="heading">Summer</p>
<p class="subHeading">from</p>
<p class="price">€180,000<span>p/week + expenses</span><span class="approx">Approx
                                                                                        
                                                                                               $211,500</span></p>
</div>
```

I am trying to grab the price here (€180,000) based on that the heading class is "Summer":

```
//p[contains(.,'Summer')]/following-sibling::p[2]
```

This returns:

€180,000p/week + expensesApprox

```
                                                                                            $211,500
```

But I only want:

€180,000

So I want to stop the XPATH before this next span class:

```
<span class="approx">Approx
                                                                                            
                                                                                                   $211,500</span>
```

I am trying variations of this without any luck!

```
//p[contains(.,'Summer')]/following-sibling::p[2] [not(preceding-sibling::span[contains(.,'p/week')])]
```

Comment: How do you use XPath? What tool do you use? Note that some tools/methods returns *first node only* while other might return *list of nodes*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this expression to get price only

```
//p[.="Summer"]/following-sibling::p[@class="price"]/text()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it:

```
//div[p["Summer"]]/p[@class="price"]/text()[not(self="span")]
```

or even simpler:

```
//div[p["Summer"]]/p[@class="price"]/text()[not(span)]
```